# python array inclusive slice index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wish to write a for loop that prints the tail of an array, **including the whole array** (denoted by i==0) Is this task possible without a branching logic, ie a `if i==0` statement inside the loop?

This would be possible if there is a syntax for slicing with inclusive end index.

```
arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(0,3):
    print arr[:-i]
```

output:

```
[]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

wanted output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `None`:

```
arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(0,3):
    print arr[:-i or None]
```

Comment: bah you beat me ... barely :P

Comment: And here I was cooking up something with `itertools.chain([None], range(-1, -3, -1))` -- This is significantly better though I would still recommend the branch I think.

Comment: even a branch like this is much clearer `print arr[:-i ] if i > 0 else arr`

Comment: I just wish these things were more readable to normal people :p

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in xrange(0, 3):
    print arr[:(len(arr) - i)]
# Output
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

The awkwardness arises from trying to take advantage of the `:-n` syntax.  Since there's no difference between `:0` and `:-0`, we can't use this syntax to distinguish `0 from the start` from `0 from the end`.

In this case it is clearer to use the `:i` indexing, and adjust the `range` accordingly:

```
In [307]: for i in range(len(arr),0,-1): print(arr[:i])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1]
[0]
```

`arr[:None]` means `0 from the end`, and usually is sufficient.

Keep in mind the `arr[:i]` translates to `arr.__getitem__(slice(None,i,None))`.  The `:` syntax is short hand for a `slice` object.  And the `slice` signature is:

```
slice(stop)
slice(start, stop[, step])
```

`slice` itself is pretty simple.  It's the `__getitem__` method that gives it meaning.  You could, in theory, subclass `list`, and give it a custom `__getitem__` that treats `slice(None,0,None)` as `slice(None,None,None)`.

Answer (score 1):

Had a brain freeze, but this would do:

```
arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(0,3):
    print arr[:len(arr)-i]
```

Although I still wish python had nicer syntax to do these kind of simple tasks.